# Wordpress site - too many redirects when selecting link

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have looked at similar questions but still receive the redirect error.When landing on a homepage URL the site resolves and displays for example http://www.test.co.uk . When selecting any link ie. http://www.test.co.uk/products the browser throws a "Too many redirects" error and the site become unusable. The only way I can get it back up is by clearing cookies and cache and trying again. What I find really confusing is that copying the http://www.test.co.uk/products link or manually typing the URL in resolves the URL correctly and I don't get "too many redirects" error. It only happens when I select a link.

I have tried the following:

- Renamed the "plugins" directory to "plugins1" to disable the plugins
- Reverted to  the default wordpress ".htaccess" file
- Ensure the site settings URLS matched in wp-admin area
- SSL is enabled on the site but not configured to be used anywhere, all links (that I'm aware of reference http://)
- Checked any redirects on the hosting via CPANEL (none exist)
- Added these to the wp-config file

  define ('WP_HOME','http://www.test.co.uk');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.test.co.uk);

I'm not sure whats changed in the last couple of days but we think a plugin got updated. Would disabling the plugins prove that its nothing to do with plugins?I'm new to WordPress so apologies if I got some terms wrong.

Any suggestions I could try looking at would be helpful. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you examine the URLs of your navigation - they might be wrong if hardcoded someway?

Answer (score 0):

try to set Home url and site url to http://www.test.co.uk from your WP admin panel

Comment: thanks, I should have been more specific , when I said "Ensure the site settings URLS matched in wp-admin area" I meant your suggestion